# setting up remote connection with an existing monetdb db

Tags: monetdb

I create a monetdb database using mserver5 (in actual fact I use R and MonetDB.R for this part).
Retrospectively (once the db has been created) I would like to do the following:

- set a remote connection to the db
- set a passphrase for the remote connection (apparently necessary)

Please note that from the manuals I think I can do the above on a new dbFarm created with monetdbd.
My problem is to do the above retrospectively on an existing db.

To start I tried to use monetdbd and pointing it to the db folder (created by mserver5) with

```
monetdbd get all myFolderCreatedWithmserver5
```

But I get

```
unable to read properties from myFolderCreatedWithmserver5: no such file or directory
```

Comment: You generally don't need `monetdbd` to establish a remote connection to a MonetDB database. By default MonetDB server instances are listening on port `50000`. This is the case even if they are started with `mserver5` directly. As long a port `50000` on your host is open, you should be able to remotely connect to the instance. E.g. `mclient -h <IP-address> -p 50000`. Connecting to a MonetDB server (almost) always requires authentication and you can change/create passwords/users without `monetdbd`.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably providing `monetdbd` the wrong folder. You can identify the "dbfarm" folder by its contents:

- `.merovingian_lock`
- `merovingian.log`
- `.merovingian_properties`
- one folder for each database

If you provide a folder above this one, or any folder of a database, you will get the above error message.